# Не понимаю почему в Laravel некорректно работают ссылки

Tags: php, laravel

Версия 5.4 Лары
Суть вот в чем. Есть страницы my-site.ru/blog и my-site.ru/blog/varianty-zabora-dlya-sada, на всех страницах есть сайд бар с ссылками на товары:

- my-site.ru/tovar1
- my-site.ru/tovar2
- my-site.ru/tovar3
- my-site.ru/tovar4

Так ссылки должны отображаться при переходе с любых страниц, но...
Если я захожу на my-site.ru/blog/varianty-zabora-dlya-sada в сайд бар записываются другие ссылки

- my-site.ru/blog/tovar1
- my-site.ru/blog/tovar2
- my-site.ru/blog/tovar3
- my-site.ru/blog/tovar4

За отображение моего сайд бара отвечает файл _left.blade.php

```
<div data-uk-sticky="bottom: true">
    <div class="left-menu">
        <span class="left-title">Услуги</span>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($left_menu_items as $item)
                <li><a href="{{$item->slug}}">{{$item->name}}</a></li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="ask">
            <div class="head">У вас есть вопросы?</div>
            <div class="ask-body">
                <p>Мы будем рады ответить на них!</p>
                <p>
                    <a data-uk-toggle href="#recall" class="btn">Обратный звонок</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Класс, отвечающий за вывод новостей

```
class FrontController extends Controller
{
    public function blog()
    {
        $posts = Post::latest()->published()->paginate(10);
        return view('layouts.blog',compact('posts'));
    }

    public function post($post)
    {
        $post = Post::where('slug',$post)->published()->firstOrFail();
        event('postHasViewed', $post); // increment view count of post when take a post. see the EventServiceProvider
        return view('layouts.post',compact('post'));
    }
}
```

Я думаю это не маршрутизация, ведь страницы существуют и при правильном вводе ссылки, все отлично работает-> значит, это либо модель, либо контроллер.
P.S. решил так:
`<li><a href="/{{$item->slug}}">{{$item->name}}</a></li>`
Но считаю это решение немного костыльным, видимо я где то ошибся в коде, раз он ведет отсчет не от корневого каталога, а от метода - родителя. Возможно в маршрутизации проблема.

```
        Auth::routes();
        Route::get('/adpanel', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin')->middleware('auth');
        Route::group(['prefix'=>'adpanel','middleware'=>'auth'], function(){
            Route::resource('categories', 'AdminController');
            Route::resource('products', 'AdminController');
            Route::resource('pages', 'AdminController');
            Route::resource('blog', 'AdminController');
            Route::resource('banner', 'AdminController');
            Route::resource('orders', 'AdminController');
            Route::resource('images', 'AdminController');
            Route::resource('regions', 'AdminController');
});
```

```
Route::get('/', 'FrontController@index')->name('front');
Route::get('/kontakty', 'FrontController@kontakty')->name('kontakty');
Route::get('/gallery', 'FrontController@gallery')->name('gallery');
Route::get('/calculator', 'FrontController@calculator')->name('calculator');
Route::get('/sitemap', 'FrontController@sitemap')->name('sitemap');
Route::get('/sitemap.xml', 'FrontController@getXmlSiteMap')->name('sitemap.xml');
Route::get('/blog', 'FrontController@blog')->name('blog');
Route::get('/blog/{post}', 'FrontController@post')->name('blog.post');
Route::post('/send', 'MailController@send')->name('mail.send');
Route::get('/skidki', 'FrontController@discounts')->name('discounts');
Route::get('/skidki/{discount}', 'FrontController@discount')->name('discounts.discount');
Route::get('/{page}', 'FrontController@getPage')->name('page');


Auth::routes();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В шаблоне в цикле вместо вывода `$item->slug` нужно использовать `route('page', ['page' => $item->slug])`. Эта функция возвращает полную ссылку на нужную страницу.
[Документация](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#named-routes)

Comment: спасибо, попробую